Retrieve SAP Security Audit logs using ABAP function
I need to retrieve SAP Security Audit logs using ABAP function.
I am able to retrieve it using, code: /osm20, on SAP GUI.
But same thing is not coming from ABAP function. The tables which I have found after my research are SYSLOG, SYSLOGB, ALSTATS, SLOG, RFC_READ_TABLE, and RSAU_READ_LOG.
But none of these tables exist in my SAP system, only DBTABLOG exists, but this doesn't hold information I need.
I need this security logs using an ABAP function. I have tried writing ABAP function, but since I don't have the tables, none of the codes are working.
Does anyone have any idea about this?

There's no official way to do that and there are many solutions. I'd say it's best to configure the Security Alerts and you can read them using BAPIs. There are other solutions at your own risk: run the unofficial report RSAU_SELECT_EVENTS and intercept its ALV output instead of displaying the data; enhance the code behind SM20 to return the data to your program instead of displaying it; etc. Sorry, but too much vague and complex to propose an answer.
